# What is the cost of a container?

Tags: docker, resources

I usually use the same image for a docker volume container as the container that is going to use it. For example,

```
dbdata:
    image: mysql
    command: echo 'DVC for MySQL'
db:
    image: mysql
    volumes_from:
        - mysql
    …
```

Tiny DVCs using images like [tianon/true](https://hub.docker.com/r/tianon/true/) are another approach. Since I don't have to pull another image, I'm pretty confident my approach uses marginally less bandwidth. But what are the downsides of my approach? You have to unpack the entire MySQL container, sure, but disk is cheap and we don't start any heavy processes; just echo, right? Does it make any practical difference in terms of machine resources and bandwidth if I recycle the main image for its DVC, or fetch a dedicated DVC type image? How can I assess this?

Comment: Close voter: Please note that [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) is a programming tool used by devops to programmatically build development environments. It evolved from [fig](http://www.fig.sh/) whose stated purpose is "Fast, isolated development environments". It is a tool for programmers, and therefore on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [tianon/dockerfiles/Dockerfile](https://github.com/tianon/dockerfiles/blob/master/true/Dockerfile) is from 2 years ago, at a time when you actually had to *run* a container, to use it as data volume container.

But since docker 1.8, you don't need to run a data volume container anymore.
You can just [`docker create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/) it.
More recently, you [`docker volume create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) it: no image needed. No cost in process or bandwidth for a DVC.

So there is no cost in term of process anymore for a data volume container.

Comment: Yeah, I had a gap. I will try again using `scratch`, then?

Comment: Well, [this looks like a massive improvement](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference). Now I just need a bot to tell me how often to completely relearn Docker.